# Why in developer mode nothing works

Tags: developer-mode, slow-response

I inherited developments made by a third party provider on our Magento instance.

When a set the developer mode nothings work anymore and it is all super slow. The layout is mess up, the buttons do not all work properly and it takes ages to load a single component.

Do I need to do some preliminary tasks (ex: delete cache, etc.) or it is caused from bad development made by the provider?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi, After changing developer mode. Execute all the magento basic commands & check.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` to switch to the developer mode, Magento neither compile code (bin/magento setup:di:compile) nor generates (deploy) static view files (bin/magento setup:static-conetnt:deploy).

On the first time visit the site after switching to the `developer` mode, Magento will force dynamic compile code and generate static content on demand during run time, that's why your site loads slowly.

So, whenever switching from the production mode to the developer mode, you should compile code and deploy(generate) static view files before visiting your site.

The command for compile code: `bin/magento setup:di:compile`
The command for deploy static view files: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

You can read more about "Deploy static view files" command from the Magento official document to get more options when using this command: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/static-view/static-view-file-deployment.html

At least, you can speed up the deploy static view files task by using `--theme` option combined with `--no-parent` option to deploy only required static view files.
For example: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Magento/luma --no-parent`
Where `Magento/luma` is your theme.

---

And for the styling and JS issues: in production mode, in some cases, your code has errors Magento allows your site (or code) to run it instead of throwing errors when you are in developer mode. So in the developer mode, you have to resolve these errors.

You can read more about how application modes work in Magento from the Magento official document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/application-modes.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, run the below command and set developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Then run below commands:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```